# Bundle product with dynamic pricing and text box input

Tags: magento, magento2

I use bundle products with custom pricing, but I also need to have a text box input where the user can enter arbitrary information (at not cost). Like a custom option, except that they will not work when using dynamic pricing.

It is possible to hack this in Magento 1 using the info from this blog post:
https://amirshakya.wordpress.com/2012/07/08/custom-options-on-a-bundle-product-in-dynamic-pricing/

But I don't know how to do this from Magento 2.
Anyone?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: 1. I didn't know there was a magento.stackexchange.com. Bad research.. 2. This question is about how to extend/program the Magento templates to allow this feature. Maybe I need to clarify.